# grouping or sorting specific rows in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

ok im new to sql and im a bit confused how can i sort  specific rows in a table on the ones i want for example if i have a table

```
cities   girls
andre    banda
andre    xampp
cox      zack
cox      magi
delan    dress
```

the above tables selects cities and girls from a table and then orders them by cities
but i want to get something like this

```
cities   girls
andre    banda
andre    xampp
delan    dress
cox      zack
cox      magi
```

as seen from the table the second one only cities cox and andre were grouped what sql statement can i run to get table 2 results thanks im using microsoft sql express

Comment: Looks like you are just ordering on girls. Is that right? Maybe your ORDER BY clause should be ORDER BY girls, cities.

Comment: no i want to order by cities the girls have just familiar names let me edit it

Comment: What are the rules for ordering, what is a "familiar name"?

Comment: @dnoeth i just edited my tables

Comment: This question, and especially the data is confusing...can you double check your data above, since it doesn't make sense.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Cities,Girls From table Order by Girls,Cities
```

this sql order by first girls ascending and cities ascending